# Null в request.getParameter(“something”)

Tags: spring, jsp

Мое приложение (Spring, JSP) не видит значение из выпадающего списка, всегда получая `null` как значение параметра `country`

JSP:

```
<select>
<c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
<option value = "$country.id_country">${country.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView addOrganization() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add");
        Organization organization = new Organization();
        modelAndView.addObject("organization", organization);
        List<Country> countries = countryService.listOfCountries();
        modelAndView.addObject("countries", countries);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addingConfirm(Organization organization, HttpServletRequest request)
{
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("confirm");
            Integer id_country = null;
        if (request.getParameter("сountry") != null
                && !request.getParameter("сountry").equals("")) {
            id_country = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("сountry"));
            organization.setCountry(id_country);
        }
        organizationService.addOrganization(organization);
        String message = "Organization was successfully added.";
        modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указали имя для select'а.

```
<select name="country">
<c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
<option value = "$country.id_country">${country.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```